# Ameliorate example sentences

Tags: vocabulary

Ameliorate in Oxford's dictionary means "make (something bad or unsatisfactory) better." Since I am new with this word, I want to know whether these sentences (that I made) are correct :

1. The professor asked a student to ameliorate his essay (to make his essay better).
2. If you desire to attain first place, you must ameliorate your performance (to make your performance better).
3. Please ameliorate your grades in order to gain a better prospect of entering a good university (to make your grades better).
4. The company decided to ameliorate their product after receving negative reviews on the internet. (To change their product so that it is better).

Please correct them if they are wrong.

PS: can you tell me the difference between repair and ameliorate. For instance, in sentence 3, can you replace ameliorate with repair?

Comment: You’d use the term if 0 is neutral and you take a -100 up to -95.

Answer (score 4):

None of your examples seem idiomatic to me.

The subject of "ameliorate" is usually a bad condition or situation, not a specific thing.

There are a number of examples in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ameliorate?locale=en) that show typical uses. Here are some of them:

> ‘the reform did much to ameliorate living standards’
> ‘It makes constructive suggestions as to how the laws may be amended to ameliorate some of the adverse impacts on young people.’
> ‘The goal is to enact a more equal distribution of wealth and power across the world by democratic means, which maintain the positive impacts of globalisation while ameliorating its negative consequences.’

"Repair" is usually used when referring to physical things that are broken; you repair a car that won't start. It can also be used figuratively, such as repairing a strained relationship or marriage.

A common word for making a specific thing better is "improve". Students are encouraged to improve their grades, and employers can improve working conditions (although "ameliorate" can also be used here: they ameliorate unsafe working conditions).

Comment: The verb that fits best in the OP's self-made examples is  *improve*

Comment: I found this sentence on Lexico. "Improved social and economic conditions enhance health status and ameliorate problems of addiction" (a problem is not a situation, so does this mean that ameliorate can also be paired with something that isnt a situation or a condition?). There are also some instances in which the word ameliorate is paired up with the word "violence" and "consequences" even "this local dependency"(All of this are found on Lexico com). Can you be more specific as to what words can be paired with ameliorate?

Comment: As with much of English, there aren't rigid rules. That's why I said "usually". It's hard to describe when it's appropriate or not.

Comment: But I'd say "problems of addiction" refers to a general condition where someone has problems, rather than a specific problem.